# AUCTeX: Some general macros/command missing from auto-completion/macro insertion

Tags: latex, auctex, auto-complete-mode

While further trying to set up a Latex environment in emacs I stumbled over a "problem" with macro-completion which I don't understand right now.

When writing Latex code the usual way to invoke macro insertion in the mini buffer is <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>RET</kbd>, then enter the macro name (using <kbd>TAB</kbd> to complete). Afterwards AUCTeX asks me for entering optional arguments, mandatory arguments, labels etc. This works quite good and is really catchy compared to other editors. It even works for `xparse` commands and self-defined macros after parsing the particular packages/infos.

But incomprehensibly there seem to be some very fundamental macros missing on my emacs. E.g. when trying to add a `\section` using the described mechanism, I hit <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>RET</kbd>; then enter `sec`, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> for auto-completion. But it directly completes to `\sectionmark` stating `[Sole Completion]`; same for `subsection` etc. and also for some commands like `\textbf`. For other Latex-commands it works like expected.

If run `LaTeX-section` manually from the mini buffer,it asks me for `level`, `title` etc. but inserts a wrong command wich has level as verbatim command name not the expected "level". E.g. `\1{title}` instead of `\section{title}`. Thus, AUCTeX seems to be missing something.

The only packages I've installed besides AUCTeX are `auto-completion-auctex` and its dependencies (`auto-complete`, `popup`, `yasnippet`). But the problem was already present before installing the completion packages.

My `.emacs` is also very reasonable:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(auto-complete-auctex auctex)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)

;; parse xparse by default
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/LaTeX-mode-setup)
(defun my/LaTeX-mode-setup ()
  (TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse"
               "latex"))
```

I may be missing something obvious since I'm still very new to emacs. Searching online, I couldn't find a similar problem, so far.

Comment: Indeed, the usual way to add a section is `LaTeX-section` (thus you don't get them at `C-c RET`, btw, it is bound to `C-c C-s` by default), but you seem to be doing something wrong there. The "level" expected by the arguments reading is not a number, but some typical values offered by completion, like "section", "chapter" etc. Try hitting TAB to get completion values.

Comment: For `\textbf` and friends, see `TeX-font` / `C-c C-f`.

Comment: Btw, as far as I can tell, `auto-completion-auctex` is not related to the problem, and I don't see why you need it. If I understand correctly, it would be an alternative to `company` or `corfu`, and you'd probably get better results with either.

Comment: Another tip, for the case of `LaTeX-section` and the wrong input. You say you are new to Emacs, and it appears you are still not well acquainted with how completion works. You may want to check some completion framework which gives you a more intuitive UI. Usual suspects are: Vertico, Ivy, Helm, Fido, etc. Plenty to choose from.

Comment: Another comment, I don't think you need (or should...) add `"latex"` to `TeX-run-style-hooks` there.  ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for your multiple hints. Maybe I misread it, but from how its written. In the docs, level sounded like an integer. Adding `latex` was just a try ;)

Comment: Oh boy, my bad. I was totally convinced that **C-c**, **RET** would suggest all possible macros and didn't look at C-c C-s. Please provide it as answer, so I can accept it and you earn the reputation ;)

Comment: That's usually the case, but not always. One relevant source of difference is `TeX-complete-expert-commands`. Regarding sectioning and font commands, I'm not sure why they are not (also) added to the `TeX-insert-macro` list. It may be the case that they technically need some sort of special treatment, or that they are simply catered for elsewhere.

Comment: And feel free to add a self-answer. As formulated, it would probably require a lengthy answer from me but, as far as I get it, and it seems to be true, the problem is just  part of the learning curve. ;-) So you can provide the answer with the actual culprit.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained by @gusbrs it was a typically beginners mistake. I was sure that *every* LaTeX macro could be invoked with **C-c, RET** (and am still convinced that this would be less confusing).

Now I know I need **C-c, C-s** for a section.

Comment: This is by design: `C-u` has different meanings when supplied to `C-c RET`, `C-c C-s` and font-related bindings like `C-c C-f C-t`.  Check AUCTeX's manual for details.